# I lose intellisense in vs 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

Ok, has anyone had this problem or know how to fix it?

I downloaded VS 2010 beta 2 and installed it, I checked it out. But now when I am editing a xaml file in VS 2008 while I have a c# class window open I lose all intellisense on my classes and it show the usings above saying `"A type or namespace 'XXXX' could not be found (are you missing a directive or assembly reference?)"`

So I have to build my project and then it all comes back.

You can imagine how unnerving this is.

Any insight?

UPDATE: 
It seems that the only thing affected was a specific project. The weird thing is that I didn't open that project int vs 2010.

I may never figure this one out. :|

Comment: So VS2008 broke after you installed VS2010?

Comment: Seems like it. I think it might have to do with .net 4.0 or something. I don't know the exact cause, and don't know how to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct fix to your issue, but you may want to consider using a tool such as ReSharper (and not just for better intellisense). I have both 2008 and 2010 installed concurrently (on Windows 7 64 bit) and they both work beautifully. Though please note that I rely on ReSharper for my intellisense, so installing that would be a workaround, not a fix to your specific problem. Of course there are no guarantees that ReSharper will work under your particular configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the .ncb file (or better still, cleaning all build directories or checking out a fresh source tree) usually solves most intellisense and source browser problems.